# cargo install cargo-generate --features vendored-openssl failed

Tags: rust, openssl, rust-cargo, terra

I am trying to install terrain from terra-money. For that, the instructions said to follow the commands. I have run these instructions on ubuntu 20.04

## 1. Set 'stable' as the default release channel:

```
rustup default stable

# 2. Add WASM as the compilation target:

rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown

# 3. Install the following packages to generate the contract:

cargo install cargo-generate --features vendored-openssl
cargo install cargo-run-script
```

but when I run it, I am getting an error in the 3rd instruction. Can anyone please help

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.72`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/cargo-installLlewUy/release/build/openssl-sys-3aec6783a3bc6a31/build-script-main` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
  OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  running "perl" "./Configure" "--prefix=/tmp/cargo-installLlewUy/release/build/openssl-sys-d4c820e0a8c7c40f/out/openssl-build/install" "no-dso" "no-shared" "no-ssl3" "no-unit-test" "no-comp" "no-zlib" "no-zlib-dynamic" "no-md2" "no-rc5" "no-weak-ssl-ciphers" "no-camellia" "no-idea" "no-seed" "linux-x86_64" "-O2" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64"
  Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1n (0x101010efL) for linux-x86_64
  Using os-specific seed configuration
  Creating configdata.pm
  Creating Makefile

  **********************************************************************
  ***                                                                ***
  ***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
  ***                                                                ***
  ***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
  ***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
  ***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
  ***                                                                ***
  ***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
  ***                                                                ***
  ***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
  ***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL file first)         ***
  ***                                                                ***
  **********************************************************************
  running "make" "depend"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', /home/raju/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-src-111.18.0+1.1.1n/src/lib.rs:477:39
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `cargo-generate v0.13.0`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installLlewUy`

Caused by:
  build failed
```

Comment: have you by any change read the big message between `*` ?

Comment: Do you have `make` installed? That is, does it work when invoked explicitly from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across the same error. I checked the OpenSSL requirements as per INSTALL file:

```
 OPENSSL INSTALLATION
 --------------------

 This document describes installation on all supported operating
 systems (the Unix/Linux family (which includes Mac OS/X), OpenVMS,
 and Windows).

 To install OpenSSL, you will need:

  * A make implementation
  * Perl 5 with core modules (please read NOTES.PERL)
  * The perl module Text::Template (please read NOTES.PERL)
  * an ANSI C compiler
  * a development environment in the form of development libraries and C
    header files
  * a supported operating system
```

I did not had perl installed, after installing it the build completed successfully.
I hope you are only missing this perl installation.